# How to set up a simple Wordpress client area?

Tags: wordpress, client, private

I have been asked by a client whether it is possible to set up a client area. Private client area in a WordPress theme Should be set up, which can only be reached via login.

So when the user in not logged in, there will be a redirect link in the main menu that links to the login page. After login, you should redirect to the homepage. The menu should be switched by a new client menu, where all private page are and of course a link to log out.

How is this simple possible?
Can it be done with the hook: `wp_login_form`.
I have created yet a login page, with above hook. And also create a client menu. This works, but when I want to log out, there is no link in the menu.

I like to hear from you. 
Casper

Comment: Could they not by just linked to the login page when they visit the site and not logged in?

Comment: You can access the site also when you are not logged in, but when you click on the link „login” you will be redirect to the login page, when you logged in, you have a private area, but you can’t logged out, because there is no logged out link... @Howlin

Comment: There should be a a logout link in the dropdown menu when you hover over your name in the top right hand corner?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css class for logged in users as WordPress appends `logged-in` to the body.

You could have `.logged-in .client`. Then have it set to `.client: display:none;` by default, so on `.logged-in .client` it would be visible (and you would change your display settings for `.logged-in .client` to be a visible one. That could be appended to your menu.

If you wanted to only use php, then this would work:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
Client-only menu
<?php } else { ?>
    Default Menu
<?php } ?>
```

Alternatively, if you set up a role for the user you can target this way (first line):

```
<?php if ( current_user_can('contributor') ) : ?>
```

WordPress also has a filter for redirection:

```
apply_filters ( 'login_redirect', string $redirect_to, string $requested_redirect_to, WP_User|WP_Error $user )
```

See http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/

Comment: Thank you @Aibrean, I have looked also inside codex and on the internet and came to the following solution: use a `Hook` to add the `login / logout` link. Only now I am searching for a solution, to stylize a custom login form, otherwise then with `wp_login_form` because it looks like, I can’t set a `placeholder` text and create a forget password link...